# Use Absolute URLs for wagtail richtext

Tags: django, html-email, wagtail

I have the following field defined on my model:

```
    email_body = RichTextField(
        verbose_name=_("Email Body"),
        help_text=_("Body of the email to send when you are out of office."),
        features=[
            "bold", "italic", "ol", "ul", "hr",
            "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6",
            "code", "superscript", "subscript",
        ],
        max_length=2048,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

However; when including links, images or documents in the features; the urls generated are all relative:

```
<p data-block-key="e0dv1"><a href="/documents/14/Kunststof_Catalogus_F1204.pdf">Kunststof Catalogus (F1204)</a></p>
<img alt="" class="richtext-image right" height="498" src="/media/images/aluminium-catalogus-f2204-page4_1.width-500.jpg" width="500">
<p data-block-key="5nssj"><a href="/nl/producten/">Producten</a></p>
<p data-block-key="aa12u">Het <a href="/nl/"><b><i>(REDACTED)</i></b></a> team, 2023</p>
```

As implied by the field name; this is used in emails; thus I cannot use relative URLs.

The HTML is generated like so:
(It is designed for template injection. Only to be used by admins.)

```
template = util.template_from("from_string", self.email_body)
body = richtext(template.render(context, request=request))
context["body"] = body
context["email_body"] = body
is_file = True
as_html = True
template_name = "office/emails/closed_email.html"
```

How can I make the richtext editor always generate full (absolute) URLs?